# getting error in inflating layout

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have made an app but when in the on create method when I am calling `setContentView(R.layout.points)`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.points);
        final CanvasView canvas = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.signature_canvas);
      //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     //  addTouchListener();

        }
```

CanvasView.java

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/26/2016.
 */
public class CanvasView extends View
{

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();


    DbActivity db =new DbActivity();
    List mPts=db.getData();
    float [] points =new float[mPts.size()];

    public CanvasView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {

        super(context,attributeSet);
       // Paint paint = mPaint;

        //canvas.translate(10, 10);

        //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        //mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPoints(points, mPaint);
    }


}
```

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/points_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.touchview.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/signature_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

DbActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/20/2016.
 */

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DbActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_db);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SQLinfo);
        DataBase db = new DataBase(this);
        try {
            db.open();
            ArrayList<Float> data = db.getData();
            db.close();


           // data.toString();
            tv.setText(data.toString());
            //Log.d("THE DATA IS ", "+ data.get(i)");

         /*  for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
            {
                tv.setText(data.get(i).toString());
                Log.d("hi", "data[i]");
            }*/

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getData()
    {
        ArrayList<Float> data= new ArrayList<>();
        DataBase db = new DataBase(this);
        try {
            db.open();
             data = db.getData();
            db.close();


    } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

modified Canvas.java

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/26/2016.
 */
public class CanvasView extends View
{

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    float[] points ;




    public CanvasView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {

        super(context,attributeSet);
        DbActivity db =new DbActivity();
        List mPts=db.getData();
         points =new float[mPts.size()];

       // Paint paint = mPaint;

        //canvas.translate(10, 10);

        //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        //mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        canvas.drawPoints(points, mPaint);
    }


}
```

Database.java

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/20/2016.
 */
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DataBase
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_X = "X";
    public static final String KEY_Y = "Y";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Details";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "DetailsTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;



    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_X + " TEXT, " + KEY_Y + " TEXT);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DataBase(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public DataBase open() throws SQLException {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String x, String y) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_X, x);
        cv.put(KEY_Y, y);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getData() {
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Point p = new Point();
        ArrayList<Float> dataPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] col = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_X, KEY_Y};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, null, null, null, null, null);
        float[] array = new float[c.getCount()];
        float[] array1 = new float[c.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                float x = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("X"));
                p.setX(x);
                dataPoints.add(p.getX());

                float y = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("Y"));
                p.setY(y);
                dataPoints.add(p.getY());
                array[i] = x;
                array1[i] = y;
                i++;
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }


        Log.d("hi", "getData() called");
        return dataPoints;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.touchview/com.example.android.touchview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.android.touchview.CanvasView
```

Comment: Please post the `CanvasView.java` file.

Comment: Problem is in your xml file. Error said even where.

Comment: Also please note that `findViewById` should be called after `setContentView`.

Comment: Hey Frogatto I have posted the CanvasView.java

Comment: I have called find View by Id after set Content view only you can see it in the code

Comment: I have updated my code please help

Comment: should I create a method for taking arraylist out of the data base

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following lines causes the error:

```
DbActivity db =new DbActivity();
List mPts=db.getData();
float [] points =new float[mPts.size()];
```

First of all, move all your initialization to the constructor method and avoid this way of initialization. Second, you shouldn't instantiate an activity.

It is recommended to move all your database level logic to a class called `DbHelper` for example, and use it in method scopes. Something like this looks fine:

```
DbHelper db;
List mPts;
float [] points;
public CanvasView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet)
{
    super(context,attributeSet);

    db = new DbHelper(...);
    mPts = new ArrayList<>();
    points = new float[...];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have seperate class for database but from database I have to take out arraylist of the points which I have to plot so that is why I have created the object of that class

Comment: @VikasKumar Ok. database access needs a context object and this object isn't accessible when classes are getting initialized, so you should access your database in a _method_ scope not in a class initialization scope.

Comment: I have uploaded the dbActivity class also have a look at it

Comment: hey I have modified Canvas.java please have a look at it

Comment: @VikasKumar You should _not_ instantiate activity derived classes in Android development. You may need to reconsider your design. Also as I already mentioned move those initializations in your method scope.

Comment: so according to you I should create a method in canvasview.java for it or anything else

Comment: @VikasKumar Access the database directly in the `CanvasView` class and don't use that activity class.

Comment: hey can you give me some hint how to do it  I am new to android please help it will be very grateful of you

Comment: Actually at first I have done this only what you have said but it was giving error Database(Context context) cannot be applied to canvasview.java

Comment: I have uploaded my database. java have a look at it

Comment: I have created object of my database.java class but it gave an error which I have mentioned above please have a look at it help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118481/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-hi-im-frogatto).

Comment: hey frogatto man I have tried everything which you have asked me to do but not getting the away with this null pointer